# Force password reset on manually created User

Tags: python, django

In my project I have an open signup form, where you can create your Company and all the information bellow it.

After that you can invite people to help you administrate the information of your company. To do that, my idea was to, when the logged user add another admin, I would create the user manually with a fake password and send a Reset Password request to the created email, so he can create his own password. The important code is below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm
...
def create_admin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AdminForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            random_pass = User.objects.make_random_password()
            user = User(username=email, email=email, password=random_pass)
            user.save()
            company.add_admin(user)
            reset_form = PasswordResetForm({'email': email})
            reset_form.save(
                email_template_name="rh/password_reset_email.html",
                subject_template_name="rh/password_reset_subject.txt")
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        form = AdminForm()
    return render(request, 'rh/create_admin.html', {'form': form})
```

Unfortunately, the above code returns a `Exception Type:    AttributeError 'PasswordResetForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'`

To note:

1. I already have a fully working reset password feature, using everything from django and custom templates. That's why I'm trying to make this work this way
2. I would like to customize the email_template_name and subject_template_name, like in my code

thanks in advance

Comment: A bit more context would help. Are you calling `is_valid()` somewhere? Forms only have `cleaned_data` after that.

Comment: I believe that the problem is not in this function per see, but in the PasswordResetForm. Nevertheless, I updated the question with the full function.

Comment: Could you add your PasswordResetForm then? Are you overriding clean in the form? You need to return `cleaned_data` there if you do. But looking at the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py) it seems cleaned_data should be there anyway, because it's created in the full_clean method as an empty dictionary.

Comment: I don't have a customized PasswordRestForm , I'm using the django default.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed I was looking at the wrong part of the code (the AdminForm part), that's why you said it wasn't important. I'm not sure I fully understand what you're doing, but what if you call `reset_form.is_valid()` before `reset_form.save`? The problem isn't in the form, you're using it in a strange way. Why use the form at all if you just want to manipulate an object?

Comment: Good call. That error was it, but it's not working yet, the email is not send and doesn't give me any errors. I'm trying to follow your idea (skipping the form) and calling directly auth_views.password_reset(...), but not working also.

Comment: That's odd, because the last step of `save` is to send the e-mail. It only sends e-mail if the user is active, but I think that's the default. Regarding skipping the form, I'd just look at the [source to PasswordResetForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L224) and take what's needed. I'll admit it's a bit of work, you have to build the context, render the subject and body and then send the e-mail.

Comment: The user must also have a usable password for the e-mail to be sent. Try using `user.set_password(random_password)` instead of passing the string to `User`. When you pass the password like that it must be an encrypted password, which is not the case.

Comment: Bingo! Worked like a charm. Didn't know this password issue. Would you mind writing a response, so I can accept it? The main points were "using auth_views.password_reset instead of the form" and the "valid password"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of dialog in comments I'll leave the response. The two issues were the way the password was being created and the form not being validated. This code should work:

```
email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
random_pass = User.objects.make_random_password()
user = User(username=email, email=email)
user.set_password(random_pass)
user.save()
company.add_admin(user)
reset_form = PasswordResetForm({'email': email})
reset_form.is_valid()
reset_form.save(
    email_template_name="rh/password_reset_email.html",
    subject_template_name="rh/password_reset_subject.txt")
return redirect('dashboard')
```

(Note that in this code I used the form and not the view, because I'm not sure about what you did with that. If this code doesn't work please correct it.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the patience and for the help. I edited the answer to reflect the correct use of the function instead of the form.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working. In fact, if I hadn't looked in the wrong place at first it would have been a lot quicker :)